# How to Map IP to doamin name in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have an IP e.g. http://11.x.x.35/xy/index.php, how can I map it to a domain e.g. xyz.xz.com in Route53. I don't want to map simple IP, I want to map IP given in above sequence without any redirection in .htaccess, is there any way????

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way. For the purposes of web browsing, DNS serves a single function: resolving names to IP addresses. No ports or URL paths are involved.

To perform a redirect, you will need to use an HTTP server.

Comment: Would you please help me setting up this in apache ubuntu??

Comment: You can hire me to do so. Though there are literally hundreds of guides online that can push you in the right direction. **Learn** the technologies you are using. Really. Learn what function they play and how to configure them to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks mate, I think I have worked on redirection before this, but its way back, need to recall all that. Thanks again :D